# Wilson's approach to renormalisation according to Peskin & Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, perturbation-theory, regularization, effective-field-theory

Although Peskin & Schroeder treats Wilson's approach to renormalisation theory in some depth, I don't get one of its main points. According to P&S (p.401):

> Imagine that we wish to compute a correlation function of fields whose momenta $p_i$ are all much less than $\Lambda$. We could compute this correlations function perturbatively using either the original Lagrangian $\cal{L}$, or the effective $\cal{L}_{eff}$ obtained after integrating over all momentum shells down to the scale for the external momenta $p_i$. Both procedures must ultimately yield the same result.

This might be a rather desirable result, but I really wonder how this could be achieved. Imagine  the non-renormalizable scalar $\phi^6$-theory in 4 dimensions. Upon slicing the high momentum Fourier components of $\phi$ away, one ends up with a free theory, as $\phi^6$ in 4D is an irrelevant operator. So in this case the 2-point function would be the free Feynman propagator, whereas perturbatively one would be completely stuck already at 1-loop level in the computation of the 2-point function. How do these 2 results fit together in the light of what P&S said?

Comment: In Wilsonian renormalization, we actually don't do anything: we just find an action that the partition function on this scale ($\Lambda$) "equals" the original cut-off action ($\Lambda_0>\Lambda$). So to understand your question, I think we should understand how in perturbative renorm. when $p<<\Lambda_0$, for an irrelevant operator, contribution of loop diagrams are negligible. However, this is how we define pert. renorma. irrelevant operators. Did I misunderstand your question? Please let me know.

Comment: @Kiarash Yes if we understood how in perturbative renormalisation for $p<<\Lambda_0$ the contributions of irrelevant operators to loop diagrams were negligible, there would be no apparent contradiction. But I wonder if this would be easy to prove or provable at all ... therefore I don't know if that way would be the right way to resolve the contradiction.